# ngLocale error with TypeScript routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am getting an error when trying to attach my config class to my angular app. I get a message saying: `$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available!` I have a reference to angular.js and angular-route.js

Here is my Config Code.

```
module TSApplication {
export class Config {
    static $inject = ["$routeProvider"];

    constructor($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        this.registerRoutes($routeProvider);
    }

    private registerRoutes(rProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider) {
        rProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "/partials/example.html", controller: "ExampleCtrl" });
    }
  }
}

(function () {
var app = TSApplication.App.angularModule;

app.config(TSApplication.Config);
})();
```

And here  is my App Module code:

```
module TSApplication {
 "use strict";
  export class App {
      static angularModule = angular.module("App", ['ngRoute']);
  }
}
(function () {
// Toaster Junk
})();
```

Am I missing something simple? If I don't include the config I do not receive an error.

Comment: Try adding `ngLocale` to the list of dependencies in your `angular.module` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing `TSApplication.Config` to the angular `config` function which is treating it as a function. Therefore, in your "constructor" `this` isn't actually what you think it is because no instance of `TSApplication.Config` was created. You could remedy this by changing `registerRoutes` to a static method and then calling it in your constructor like this `Config.registerRoutes($routeProvider);`.